# Rails 4 - child record destroyed with AJAX in nested form but form still submits this record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a recipe and ingredient model association set as

**Model Association**

```
Recipe has_many :ingredients
accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

Ingredient belongs_to :recipe
```

and in nested form, I have a link that destroys ingredient record with Ajax.

**View**

```
<%= simple_form_for @recipe do |f| %>
    ...
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :ingredients do |i| %>
        <%= i.input_field :name %>
        <%= link_to "Delete", recipe_ingredient_path(@recipe, i.object), method: :delete, remote: true %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Destroying nested resource works perfectly but the problem occurs with this nested form submitting parameters that still contain the destroyed resource attributes.
Therefore, with the form update, recipes_controller complains about the record to be updated that has already been destroyed.

**Recipe Controller**

```
...
def update
  if @recipe.update(recipe_params)
    respond_with(@recipe)
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
...

private
  def recipe_params
    params.require(:recipe).permit(:title, :image, :serving, :prep, :cook, :steps, ingredients_attributes: [:id, :name, :_destroy])
  end
```

**Ingredient Controller (only have destroy to handle Ajax response)**

```
def destroy
  @ingredient = Ingredient.destroy(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Below is the error I'm getting.
If you look at the requested parameters there is still one ingredient resource passing in
even though all ingredients were destroyed properly before the submit.

I understand what the problem is but I'm having difficulty tackling this problem.

[image: error message]

Comment: Examine the DOM, they're probably still there (perhaps hidden).

Comment: Thanks. That was it. I forgot about hidden field that Simple Form generates.